# ionic analytics, events not showing on ionic.io dashboard

Tags: android, ios, analytics, ionic-framework

I've followed the steps here ([Ionic Analytics](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/analytics-from-scratch)) and configured the basic example to make the analytics work. What is happening is that I can't see any event listed on the app dashboard in the ionic.io site.

I tried to navigate the app from ionic serve and from an Android device, but in both cases nothing shows up in the dashboard.

Anyone who can help?

The tutorial says that "After a few minutes you'll be able to go to the 'analytics' dashboard for your app on the Ionic.io website and see some basic analytics data showing up." How many minutes should I wait? 
Is there any other code I need to add in the app besides the snippet listed on the tutorial?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?